# How can I check if a rotated rect intersects a non-rotated rectangle?

Tags: rectangles, collision-detection

I have a rotated retangle and a rectangle. Both are defined by their corners (however, for the non-rotated ones I also have access to topLeft, topRight, etc).

Is there a way I can check if they intersect? (It would be enough to know if they intersect, even without knowing the extent of their intersection).

[image]

I found solutions for two non-rotated rectangles and two [rotated rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962379/how-to-check-intersection-between-2-rotated-rectangles#:%7E:text=For%20each%20edge%20in%20both,found%2C%20you%20have%20an%20intersection.) . Technically the solutions for two rotated rectangles could work in this case but I think that, since i know one of them is axis-aligned, there might be a faster way..

Comment: A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I fixed it.